# Get output only the Version of Aks using powershell

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-powershell

Iam begineer level in powershell, Hope you can help me with a problem trying to execute a script block

```
$CurrentVersion = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName $AKsResourceGroup -Name $AKSName | Select-Object -Property KubernetesVersion
"The CurrentVersion is $CurrentVersion"
```

**output getting using above script:**

The CurrentVersion is @{KubernetesVersion=1.23.8}

but i need to get the output only the version like  **The CurrentVersion is 1.23.8**, which property or filter to use to get this logic, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does this command help? `$CurrentVersion = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName v-sairam-MT -Name nov9pipeline313907973b | select -ExpandProperty KubernetesVersion
"The CurrentVersion is $CurrentVersion" `. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/y3VATNC.png)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

Make use of **`ExpandProperty`** which expands details about a particular property.

```
$CurrentVersion = Get-AzAksCluster -ResourceGroupName RGName -Name AksClusterName | select -ExpandProperty KubernetesVersion

"The CurrentVersion is $CurrentVersion"
```

**Response:**

[image]